# Can I install an automatic garage door opener in this old house?

Tags: garage-door-opener

Right now I have to manually open, close, and lock the garage door every time I need to exit/enter my garage. The house is 80+ years old and hasn't had any work done on it since. Would this be a difficult project? Would I have to replace anything due to its age? I'm not really a handyman, the most I've done is replace a light fixture or doorknob.
Some pictures of the [garage](https://imgur.com/a/UqSXRSi).

Comment: Looks like it might work. Hard to tell for sure from pictures. It looks like the rails are very close to the ceiling. That may pose a problem for an out-of-the-bx installation, but it might be "do-able".

Comment: If that door is relativity easy to raise by hand, then a garage door opener should work.  Will need power to be added close to the opener, but I think you still have to lock it by hand.  Should not be much harder than replacing a doorknob and fixture(together), a few screws and wire connections.

Comment: I don't see the spring assist. Where is it? Electric openers put stress on the top of the  door and can pull apart these old wooden doors. Personally I would stick with manual  muscle operation.

Comment: @JimStewart  Who needs gym membership without spring assist.

Comment: There must be a spring assist, I just don't see it

Comment: Perhaps it's so old it has counterweights on (or in) the opposite wall. Or the springs are all the way behind it, since the clearance is so low.

Comment: OP, how about telling us how your door is balanced--springs or counterweights?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue is the little clearance between the top of the door and your garage ceiling.

You will need an opener with a low clearance.  Installing an opener can be tricky. If you are not very handy and good at overcoming issues as they arise, I would suggest you hire a company to install an opener.  Let them overcome the problems.  They will, or should give a warranty.

Finally you will need to get an outlet to the ceiling of the garage, or have an extension cord run across the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

This situation might be resolved with a "wall mounted" garage door opener, but I don't understand the mechanism in the this OP's door. Looks like support cables going to the bottom of the door, but the spring mechanism is not showing. Is there a separate spring for each side? Or is there an axle connecting the two sides?

https://youtube.com/shorts/16pMQ0-E1Yw?feature=share3

https://youtube.com/shorts/NMfNHpQPiQk?feature=share3

https://youtu.be/SSYuqk4XGyQ

Answer (score 0):

You state: "I'm not really a handyman, the most I've done is replace a light fixture or doorknob." My recommendation is to get a professional or two in to look at it and give you a quote. This is not a beginner project and if you make a mistook you can be seriously injured. The professionals have the skill and knowledge to properly advise you on what you can or cannot do. If you go with one of them you will also get a guarantee which will let you keep from worrying.